# Chrome extension - run script after JS function call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an interesting problem where I want a Chrome extension that I am building to modify the DOM after a certain JS function has been called.

The extension I'm building is simply modifying the dates shown on a Dell laptop warranty lookup page.

Here is a sample warranty lookup page from Dell:  http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/FM4Z9S1

To get to the warranty information, I would need to click the "Warranty" link, and enter the correct captcha.  Clicking the "Submit" button triggers a call to `submitCaptcha()` on Dell's website, and **after** this function is called, I want my extension to change the dates displayed to a different format.

The content-scripts that I was previously using looked like this:

```
"matches": ["*://*/*"],
"js": ["content_script.js"],
"run_at": "document_end"
```

But since the dates that I want to modify aren't on the DOM until after the `submitCaptcha()` function on the page is called, running the script at "document_end" doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't know a lot about `chrome extensions`, but here is an idea!

You use the `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` function to modify the inline `onclick` attribute of the submit `<button>`.

Like this (it would be in your `content_script.js` file):

```
var tabIndex = yourtabindex;
var injectedCode = "\
  var button = document.getElementById('btnSubmitCaptchawarranty')\
  button.setAttribute( 'onclick' , 'submitCaptcha(); yourfunc(); return false;' );\
  function yourfunc(){\
      (..)\
  }\
";


chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabIndex,{
    code:injectedCode
});
```

Would that work? Hope it helps!

Comment: Nope, will not work: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment